# A motherboard has 2 x PCIe slots. Can onboard DVI be used too?

Tags: multiple-monitors, motherboard, pci-express

I am looking at a motherboard, a Z68, which has two PCIe slots. I notice that it also has an onboard DVI port. While using the PCIe slots, am I able to also use the onboard DVI slot?

For example: Two dual PCIe cards give me 4 monitors. Would I be able to squeeze out a fifth monitor using the onboard DVI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me [it seems](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/289385-12-discrete-graphics-card-integrated-graphics-simultaneously) (first answer from markmywords) as you **must** have at least one monitor on integrated GPU - thus, in common, I see nothing against 5-6 monitors

See also this [announce about Lucid Virtu GPU Virtualization](http://www.pcper.com/reviews/Processors/Lucid-Virtu-GPU-Virtualization-Software-Review-Sandy-Bridge-and-Discrete-coexist?aid=1086&type=expert) (sw, mentioned in topic above, somehow related to z68)

Comment: the Lucid GPU virtualisation software allows switchable graphics on the z68 platform iirc

Comment: this is what I am looking for. It will help me when choosing a board. Hope it works as well as they state. Good link, thanks.